# How to run a MongoDB query in Golang with $cond

Tags: mongodb, go

I try to run a MongoDB query in Golang and getting some errors.
I would like to update the field *"expiresAt"* with a new timestamp if the field *"section.gateBack"* is equal to 0.

The data model looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "78b0e7de-c24c-11eb-8529-0242ac130003",
  "expiresAt": "2021-04-22T14:06:55.069Z",
  "section": {
    "gateFront": 1,
    "gateMiddle": 1,
    "gateBack": 0
  }
}
```

In the first try I wrote the query like I do other (simple) $set-operations but this time with *$cond* to work with *if-else*:

```
filter := bson.M{
    "_id": iD,
}

update := bson.M{
    "$set": bson.M{
        "expiresAt": bson.M{
            "$cond": bson.M{
                "if": bson.M{
                    "$and": []bson.M{
                        {"section.gateBack": bson.M{"$eq": 0}},
                        {"section.gateBack": bson.M{"$exists": true}},
                    },
                },
                "then": time.Now().AddDate(0, 1, 0),
                "else": time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 1),
            },
        },
    },
}

res, err := s.coll.UpdateOne(
    ctx,
    filter,
    update,
)
```

But with this update-operation I get the following error:

```
multiple write errors: [{write errors: [{The dollar ($) prefixed field '$cond' in 'expiresAt.$cond' is not valid for storage.}]}, {<nil>}]
```

I found a question on MongoDB developers side which says that the update-value has to be an array:
https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongoerror-the-dollar-prefixed-field-cond-in-energy-cond-is-not-valid-for-storage/16448

This makes sense when I read the official documentation of MongoDB for the operation *UpdateOne()* with Aggregation pipeline:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#example-2

So I have changed my update value and append it to an array of bson.M:

```
filter := bson.M{
    "_id": iD,
}


var pipeline []bson.M

update := bson.M{
    "$set": bson.M{
        "expiresAt": bson.M{
            "$cond": bson.M{
                "if": bson.M{
                    "$and": []bson.M{
                        {"section.gateBack": bson.M{"$eq": 0}},
                        {"section.gateBack": bson.M{"$exists": true}},
                    },
                },
                "then": time.Now().AddDate(0, 1, 0),
                "else": time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 1),
            },
        },
    },
}
pipeline = append(pipeline, update)

res, err := s.coll.UpdateOne(
    ctx,
    filter,
    pipeline,
)
```

But now I get the error like this:

```
cannot transform type []primitive.M to a BSON Document: WriteArray can only write a Array while positioned on a Element or Value but is positioned on a TopLevel
```

I don't know how to build the operation to make it runnable.

My aim is to update the field *expiresAt* with different timestamps depending on the values of '*section*'. I also want to make it more complex with nested if-else but should first work with simple conditions.

Something like this:

```
update := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "expiresAt": bson.M{
                "$cond": bson.M{
                    "if": bson.M{
                        "$and": []bson.M{
                            {"section.gateBack": bson.M{"$eq": 0}},
                            {"section.gateBack": bson.M{"$exists": true}},
                        },
                    },
                    "then": time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 1),
                    "else": bson.M{
                        "$cond": bson.M{
                            "if": bson.M{
                                "$and": []bson.M{
                                    {"section.gateMiddle": bson.M{"$eq": 0}},
                                    {"section.gateMiddle": bson.M{"$exists": true}},
                                },
                            },
                            "then": time.Now().AddDate(0, 1, 0),
                            "else": ...,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

Does someone know how to write an *updateOne*-operation in *Golang* which is working with *if-else* as *$cond*?

Comment: Why didn't you make `"section.gateBack": 0` condition as part of the _filter_?

Comment: @prasad_ I don't want to add the condition to *filter* because if  *"section.gateBack": 0* does not match I want to check in the *else*-part the next  value *"section.gateMiddle": 0*. And if this does not match then check if *"section.gateFront": 0*.

Comment: So, if one of the three values is _zero_, then you want to update?

Comment: @prasad_ Yes, that right. Depending on which value is zero, I want to update the field *expiresAt* with a different timestamp.

Comment: Then put a `$or` condition in the _filter_.

Comment: @prasad_ But with *filter* I'm finding the document which I want to update.

Comment: `$cond` is an aggregation operator, not an update operator.

Comment: @Joe The following post says that *$cond* is available for *updateOne()* operation since Mongo v4.2:
https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/conditional-object-update/6166/2

Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: In order to use aggregation operators with 4.2+ you need to pass an array of pipeline stages as the update, instead of a single object.

Comment: Try using [$switch - case](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) aggregation operator if you want to update a different value for different condition. But, you have to use the **Updates with the Aggregation Pipeline**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bson.A{bson.M{...}, bson.M{...}}` instead of `[]bson.M{...}` the mongo driver aliases map and slice types and looks for `bson.M{}` `bson.A{}` types when converting your query.

Comment: mongodb should have stuck with the primitive types in the driver so that we could just define queries like anything else is go but ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. I totally forgot to post the solution.
Like @prasad_ was saying, I tried to use the switch-case operator, but with `UpdateOne()`.

```
ctx := context.Background()

filter := bson.M{
    "_id": ID,
}

back := bson.M{
    "case": bson.M{
        "$and": []bson.M{
            {"$gt": []interface{}{"$section.gateBack", 0}},
            {"$exists": []interface{}{"$section.gateBack", true}},
        },
    },
    "then": time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 1),
}

middle := bson.M{
    "case": bson.M{
        "$and": []bson.M{
            {"$gt": []interface{}{"$section.gateMiddle", 0}},
            {"$exists": []interface{}{"$section.gateMiddle", true}},
        },
    },
    "then": time.Now().AddDate(0, 1, 0),
}

front := bson.M{
    "case": bson.M{
        "$and": []bson.M{
            {"$gt": []interface{}{"$section.gateFront", 0}},
            {"$exists": []interface{}{"$section.gateFront", true}},
            {"$in": []interface{}{"$section.access", []string{"gate", "door"}}},
        },
    },
    "then": time.Now().AddDate(1, 0, 0),
}

cases := bson.A{back, middle, front}

update := []bson.M{
    {
        "$set": bson.M{
            "expiresAt": bson.M{
                "$switch": bson.M{
                    "branches": cases,
                    "default":  time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 0),
                },
            },
        },
    },
}

res, err := coll.UpdateOne(
    ctx,
    filter,
    update,
)
if err != nil {
    return 0, err
}
```